# Syncing one remote git repo with other

Tags: git, synchronization, repository, git-remote, mirror

I would like to create like a 'mirror repo'. 
Lets say that there is a **remote repository** from which I can only **clone**. 
Now, there's a **second, mine remote repo** and I would like it to '*monitor*' the **first** remote and automatically update if there is anything new.

I mean without involving the local repo. It's how I do that already. 
I checkout the **first** repo, make changes and push it to the **second** one.

But it takes too much time. I would like it to automatically *sync* for example once a day.

Comment: can't you use a crontab to make make sync ?

Comment: May I assume that you don't have shell access to the second server? (If you had, you could fetch directly from there.)